# Unable to make IPython to read shell variables

Tags: ipython

I run the command in IPython

```
cd $cs<TAB>
```

but it does not allow me to expand the path.

**How can you make IPython to read shell variables?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you mean by 'shell variables'. If you mean variables set in the shell ('environment variables'): you can read them with os.environ...

```
import os
cs = os.environ.get('cs')
runstring = "cd %s" (cs)
...
```

Comment: Also in modern versions of IPython you can do `cs = !echo $cs; runstring = "cd %s" % (cs[0])`